# XP pauses at the welcome screen for about 1 minute

Tags: windows-xp, boot, pause

Every time I start up my computer, Windows XP Pro will hang at the welcome screen (I don't have any user accounts) for about 1 minute before showing the desktop.

Anyone encountered this issue before and know what's causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Odd as this might sound, try putting a disc in your DVD drive.  Without one in my Windows XP system's drive during startup, there is a long pause that sounds similar to yours.  Is it a long shot?  Yes.  Is it easy to try?  Also yes.

Comment: Very interesting, but even if it solves the problem, it would be nice to know why.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. On the other hand, trying to understand why everything works the way it does in Windows seems like a ticket to crazyville.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have either a disconnected printer or mapped network drive. Your computer is trying to locate one of these devices/machines and will get past the welcome screen once it times out.

Either that or you have way too many things loading at boot. Click on Start > Run and type MSCONFIG. You can disable a lot of items from starting up.

[image]

Under the Services Tab be sure to uncheck Show Microsoft Processes and you will see from your list of installed applications which ones have services starting at boot. Also under the Startup tab you can disable applications from booting.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather well-known **DHCP issue**/bug -- it happens to me all the time.

Unfortunately, there's no 100% foolproof fix.

You can avoid it if you can assign a permanent IP address to your adapter, so that your computer doesn't have to wait for the router to give it an IP address dynamically. Alternatively, turn off your network cards and reboot: you should see that it doesn't happen again.